# esperar a que una promesa termine para continuar

Tags: javascript, firebase, promesas

Buen dia,

estoy trayendo datos de Firestore en una funcion de Vuex para armar un array, todo funciona de maravilla, lo que necesito es recorrer unas ventas (lo cual funciona bien), empujarlas a un array llamado ventas  y luego haré con el otras cosas que no vienen aqui al caso

el problema es que me muestra primero el ventas.length en cero, luego me muestra las ventas por separado, como puedo hacer para esperar a que se recorran las ventas, se empujen array para luego si operar el array

Gracias!!

```
async productosMasVendidosPorGrupoClientes(context,parametros){   
                 
            try{    
                //traigo los clientes que pertenecen a ese grupo
                let docRef = doc(db, "grupos", parametros.idGrupo);
                let docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);        
                if(docSnap.exists())
                {
                    let ventas = [];
                    let integrantes = docSnap.data().integrantes;                 
                                  
                    integrantes.forEach((nombreCliente)=>{
                        const q = query(collection(db, "ventas"),
                        where("fecha", ">=", parametros.fechaDesde),
                        where("fecha", "<=", parametros.fechaHasta),
                        where("cliente", "==", nombreCliente));

                        getDocs(q).then((snapshot) => {
                            if(snapshot.size>0){
                                snapshot.docs.forEach((venta) => {
                                    console.log(venta.data())
                                    //aqui recorre bien las ventas y empujo al array ventas
                                    ventas.push(venta.data())
                                })                                
                            }
                        }).catch((err) =>{
                            console.log(err.message);
                        });
                    })


                    console.log(ventas.length)
                    //este console.log me muestra 0, primero esto

                     //;luego muestra las ventas iteradas mas arriba, como puedo hacer para que primero se empujen las ventas al array y luego poder aqui hacer algo con el array ventas   
                }
                else
                {Swal.fire("No existe el grupo a consultar","","error")}

            }
            catch(e){
                console.error("Error leyendo documentos: ", e);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Qué versión de Vue estás utilizando? Por qué no estás utilizando los `ref` y los `computed`? qué tal `await getDocs();` eso deberia devolverte lo que buscas.

Answer (score 0):

El evento `forEach` no se puede esperar, use `for()`

o

```
await Promise.all()
```